# OSGi memory management

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have theoretical question about OSGi memory management.

Let’s say we have some OSGi container (Felix for instance), and let’s suppose I created some bundle with memory leak.

And here are some questions that I have:

1. Is there any way to limit memory
   consumption for this “failure”
   bundle? For example if it exceeds
   memory limit – OSGi container would
   send me an email, uninstall it or
   something else?
2. How does memory consumption in
   bundle “A” affect bundle “B”. For
   example if “A” causes out of memory error
   would it blow up whole OSGi
   container?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The complete OSGi framework runs in a single virtual machine. Only that each bundle is loaded by a different classloader. But all bundles share the same heap and if one bundle leaks memory, this affects the whole OSGi based application.

So yes, if an OutOfMemoryError is caused by one bundle, the whole container is "blown up".

(BTW: if someone drops a bundle into your container that does a `System.exit()`, then again the whole container is stopped without a warning - bundles do not live in isolated contexts like some "virtual machines inside a jvm")

Comment: +1: The permission layer of the OSGi framework should however protect you against abusive calls to methods like `System.exit()`.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that answers my question.

Comment: Andreas, you haven't answered questions 1 - do you know if there is a way to limit a bundle's memory ?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. I'm not aware of *any* mechanism that calculates the memory footprint of a collection of objects on the heap.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to check this study: http://vmkit.llvm.org/publications/osgi_dsn.html